# Tensorflow He initializer for layers with with skip connections

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras

In tensorflow [he initializer](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.01852.pdf) is implemented [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/initializers/he_uniform). My network has additive skip connections (like residual networks) in it. So the `fan_in` should change accordingly if unit variance is to be maintained by the network. Does the tensorflow initializer take care of that or do i need to write my own initializer for that?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, in Resnet with skip connections, we will use `He Initializer` which will address the issue which you have mentioned.

However, if you want to make sure Variance to be maintained you can use `Glorot Initialization` which was developed for the same purpose as explained below.

**Glorot** and **Bengio** propose a way to significantly alleviate
the unstable gradients problem. They point out that we need the signal to
flow properly in both directions: in the forward direction when making
predictions, and in the reverse direction when backpropagating gradients.
We don’t want the signal to die out, nor do we want it to explode and
saturate. For the signal to flow properly, the authors argue that we need the
variance of the outputs of each layer to be equal to the variance of its
inputs, 2 and we need the gradients to have equal variance before and after
flowing through a layer in the reverse direction (please check out the paper
if you are interested in the mathematical details). It is actually not
possible to guarantee both unless the layer has an equal number of inputs
and neurons (these numbers are called the fan-in and fan-out of the layer),
but **Glorot** and **Bengio** proposed a good compromise that has proven to
work very well in practice: the connection weights of each layer must be
initialized randomly.

Since Initialization parameters depend on the activation function in the layer, the below table is suggested Initializer for different activation functions.

[image]

I hope this answers your question, Happy Learning!